# Validating minutes and seconds in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, activerecord, time

I'm currently trying to validate a time based attribute called `duration` for one of my models. The attribute, would accept something along the lines of `01:30` as a valid value. The goal is to have a 4 digit time-code (minutes and seconds) with a colon in between the two. Both minutes and seconds limit in range `59` and cannot have `00:00` as a value. The regex I currently have doesn't seem to work:

```
validates :duration, presence: true, format: {with: /A([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]z/}
```

Comment: Regex are not good for testing ranges of values. They are good for pulling values from a string though, so use it for that and then apply logic to see if the values are in range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)`(?!00:00)`, the rest of the regex is a simple minutes/seconds validation.

```
/\A(?!00:00)[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\Z/
```

---

```
if subject =~ /\A(?!00:00)[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\Z/
    # Successful match
else
    # Match attempt failed
end
```

---

[REGEX DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/iFL7rhzvNB)

Answer (score 0):

You may try following regex:

```
(?!00\:00)([0-5][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9])
```